# ggplot printing regression equations where there are multiple lm on one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression

Here is the subset of data from my dataframe which is used in this plot;

```
Year    region  gear    Species.Code    query   LPUE
1974    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Pre     0.31
1975    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Pre     0.26
1976    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Pre     0.33
1977    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Pre     0.17
1978    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Pre     0.2
1979    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Pre     0.22
1980    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Pre     0.38
1981    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Pre     0.51
1982    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Pre     0.57
1983    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Pre     0.45
1984    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Post    0.43
1985    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Post    0.33
1986    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Post    0.21
1987    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Post    0.69
1988    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Post    0.65
1989    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Post    0.37
1990    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Post    0.35
1991    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Post    0.15
1992    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Post    0.21
1993    Cyprus  creel   LOB             Post    0.17
```

I have generated a line plot of time-series data and fitted two linear regressions one for the data up to 1984 and one for the data after 1984. 
Using the following code;

```
ggplot(subset(A7,region=="Cyprus"&gear=="creel"&Species.Code=="LOB"),aes(x=Year,y=LPUE,shape=query))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_smooth(method="lm")+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'black'))
```

I would like to know firstly how I can print the equations on the plot (other examples I have found on stack overflow only deal with one lm) and secondly how I can save the lm models so that I can do a statistical test of the significance between them.

Comment: A screen shot of what you have would help as you probably didn't include enough data to reproduce what you have.

Comment: If you want to do statistical tests, I'd suggest to fit the models outside of ggplot.

Comment: sorry @MikeWise i'm not familiar with how to add a screen shot. I can only see how to add images from the internet.

Answer (score 2):

you can add several regression lines to a ggplot by stacking geom_smooth commands. I would suggest to create separate data frames for the two models you want to fit.

```
data_upto84 <- subset(A7, year<1985)
data_from84 <- subset(A7, year>1984)

ggplot(data_upto84, aes(YEAR, LPUE)) + 
stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_normal) +
geom_smooth(method = 'lm') +
geom_smooth(data = data_from84, aes(YEAR, LPUE), method = 'lm')
```

On your second question: "secondly how I can save the lm models so that I can do a statistical test of the significance between them".
You save a model by assigning it to an object:

```
model1 <- lm(LPUE ~ 1 + YEAR, data = data_upto84)
model2 <- lm(LPUE ~ 1 + YEAR, data = data_from84)
```

It is not clear to me what you want to test with these models. Standard model comparison (for example using the anova function) will not be valid as you run the models on two different samples.